# How can you have a meson subproject that depends on another subproject?

Tags: meson-build

I've read through the documentation for meson a few times and looks for other people having a similar circumstance, and maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

If I have Project A rely on Project B, I simply put a subprojects folder in the root and put my Project B in there. Then I can use subproject('Project_B') and it will give me the ability to grab Project_B_dep.

What do I do if Project A relies on Project B and that relies on Project C? Can both Project B and project C be in the same subprojects folder or do I need to then add a subprojects folder in Project B and build a whole hierarchy tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern versions of Meson, you only need to put the subproject in the subprojects folder for any project directly consuming them, and Meson will "auto promote" subprojects from the subprojects to the main project as long as there are no conflicts (ie, if Project A relies on C 2.1 and Project B relies on C 3.0 there's a conflict and you'll have to manually fix that).

You can, however just put them in Project A/subprojects and that will work fine.